# Where can I find the official Ubuntu MultiArch support documentation?

Tags: multiarch

The official Ubuntu documentation site appears to contain no documentation in relation to multiarch.

Does anyone know where can I find the official documentation.

Comment: What exactly as you after; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch was the first result on a simple search using `multiarch site:*.ubuntu.com` and my default startpage.com search.  That wasn't the only result either...   *Providing clues as to your Ubuntu product can also be useful; as some documentation is Ubuntu product specific, and you gave no clues as to if you're after Ubuntu Core docs, Ubuntu Server docs, Ubuntu Desktop docs etc*

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for... Does this help? https://lima-vm.io/docs/config/multi-arch/

Comment: @guiverc Thanks that exactly was I was after.  I found the debian docs already but not the ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch

As stated in a [*prior*] comment, you didn't state which Ubuntu product, as many docs are specific to that product (ie. *there are Ubuntu Core docs, Ubuntu Server docs, Ubuntu Desktop docs etc*), thus Ubuntu product/release can impact the best tools.

The result I provided is also the first result of a search using

`multiarch site:*.ubuntu.com`

using my default search engine (https://www.startpage.com/) with many other suggestions offered.  Limiting the results using the `site:` option I find very useful, as rather often the official docs are the most accurate (*with date & release details usually easy to detect; let alone adjustable via URL for many pages too*)

Comment: low value answer.. but at least question has 'answer' (rather than being still open)